# How to define the end of a function when i rerun the same function?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am using the following function to crawl entire websites, extracting all links from each page using cheerio.

```
const crawlUrl = async (urlCrawl) => {
    try {
        //Check if url was already crawled
        if (urlsCrawleadas[urlCrawl]) return;
        urlsCrawleadas[urlCrawl] = true;

        console.log('Crawling', urlCrawl)
        const response = await fetch(urlCrawl)
        const html = await response.text()

        //Extract links from every page
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const links = $("a").map((i, link) => link.attribs.href).get()

        const { host } = urlParser.parse(urlCrawl)

        //Filter links from same website, and external sites
        const newLinks = links
            .map(link => {
                if (!link.includes(host.hostname) && link.includes('http://') || !link.includes(host.hostname) && link.includes('https://')) {
                    const nueva = urlParser.parse(link)
                    othersUrls.push(nueva.host.hostname)
                }
                return link
            })
            .filter(link => link.includes(host.hostname))
            .map(async link => await crawlUrl(link))

        //remove duplicates urls from 
        const test = [...othersUrls.reduce((map, obj) => map.set(obj, obj), new Map()).values()]
        
        //export urls
        let writer = FS.createWriteStream('data.txt')
        writer.write(test.toString())

        return 'End'

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('function crawler', error)
    }

}
```

The problem is that I cannot define when the crawler has finished going through all the urls. This makes it unable to tell the front when the full task has finished.

Regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: since I see you are calling crawlUrl recursively, it may never end as long as it still finds links pointing to pages having links themeselves. So you could set an argument like deepLevels that you are going to decrement at each nested call as long as it hits zero. Or you could keep track of the operations setting the value of a global variable but yet without having control of execution flow.